# Add Horizontal Lines Between Elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a horizontal line between two elements, like LinkedIn:
[image]
I can't get the line on the left of the image to stop at the left side count. I've been Googling for a long time and can't find this particular case. I'm sure it's out there, but I haven't found it. This is how far I've gotten:

The HTML:

```
<label>count</label>
<div class="img">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh235.png" />
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div.img {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
}
div.img:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 51%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    text-align: right;
    height: 1px;
    content: '\a0';
    background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XWVxk/1465/

[image]
I also thought that this structure might be an option (div in between elements with the div having a border):

The HTML:

```
<label>count</label>
<div class="hr-line"></div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh235.png" />
```

And the CSS:

```
div.hr-line {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7A7A7A;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XWVxk/1464/

But it doesn't work exactly either. If anyone could touch up either attempt, it would be great.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## Method 1: Flexbox

```css
.divided {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.divider {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<p class="divided">
  <span>Content 1</span>
  <span class="divider"></span>
  <span>Content 2</span>
</p>
```

[image: flexbox method explanation]

Because the parent is flexbox, we can just tell the `.divider` element to fill all available space, by setting `flex-grow: 1;`.

---

## Method 2: Solid background color

```css
.divided {
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 45%, black 45%, black 55%, transparent 55%);
}

.divided span {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.divided span:last-of-type {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<p class="divided">
  <span>Content 1</span>
  <span>Content 2</span>
</p>
```

[image: background-color method explanation]

We are giving `.divided` a linear-gradient as a background, to make a display that looks like a line of the color you want, then settings the `<span>`'s to have the same color background, so they cover the line.

You can accomplish the same thing quite a few different ways, such as using a pseudo element as the line, then giving the `<span>`'s a `position` and `z-index`.

What are the drawbacks of this method? It *only* works with a background that's a solid color. Throw an image, gradient, or anything that the content's background is gonna cover, and you'll end up with a display like so:

[image: comparing the methods]

Comment: Great answer, especially with the logic breakdown.

Comment: The comments are only meant to add to the answer / question, but I have to say that this is a perfectly written answer. Well done.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another one:

```css
.box { 
  width: 100%;  
  display:-moz-flex;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-ms-flex;
  display:flex;
}

hr {
  /*border: .5px solid #000;*/
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.hr-line {
  -moz-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <label>count</label>
    <div class="hr-line"><hr></div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh235.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. But any way to get the thickness of the line down? That's pretty thick for the smallest thickness of 1px.

Comment: @mikeyaworski - Yep, simply remove the line `border: 1px ...` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XWVxk/1469/)

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox. Any way to update this so it does?